# How to initialize javascript on a webpage

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use this script to fade out text on scroll: http://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/sfutl/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
$(".top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
});
```

In the HTML, the div containing the text is given the class "top", and the JS is in an external document called "scroll.js", which I've included in the header with:

```
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
```

How do I actually get the script to initialize on the page?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Your codepen works

Comment: Do you have a tag with a class attribute with a value of top in your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the script tag from the head of your document to just before the closing body tag of your document.

Comment: @fourfiftythree Accept this answer, if this helped you. To accept, click on the tick mark below the votes of this answer. :)

Comment: @fourfiftythree, yes thanks Arjun, accepting the answer would be good :)